# How to group by a variable and see if they have another observation within a given time frame, R

Tags: r

I have the something like the following:

```
person_ID     visit date       
1               2/25/2001           
1               2/30/2001           
1               4/2/2001            
2               3/18/2004           
3               9/22/2004             
3               10/27/2004          
3               5/15/2008
```

I want to add another column to see if the person has a reoccurring observation within 90 days, like:

```
person_ID     visit date       reoccurrence
1               2/25/2001           1
1               2/30/2001           1
1               4/2/2001            0
2               3/18/2004           0
3               9/22/2004           1   
3               10/27/2004          0
3               5/15/2008           0
```

any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second 'date' is not `2/30/2001`, convert the 'visit_date' to `Date` class, grouped by 'person_id', get the `diff`erence between current and next 'visit_date' in 'day', check if it is less than 90, replace the `NA` with 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
   mutate(visit_date = mdy(visit_date)) %>%
   group_by(person_ID) %>% 
   mutate(reoccurrence = replace_na(+(difftime(lead(visit_date), 
       visit_date, units = 'day') < 90), 0)) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  person_ID visit_date  reoccurrence
#      <int> <date>     <dbl>
#1         1 2001-02-25     1
#2         1 2001-02-28     1
#3         1 2001-04-02     0
#4         2 2004-03-18     0
#5         3 2004-09-22     1
#6         3 2004-10-27     0
#7         3 2008-05-15     0
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, visit_date := as.IDate(visit_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
     ][, reoccurence := +(difftime(shift(visit_date, type = 'lead'), 
       visit_date, units = 'day') < 90))
        ][is.na(reoccurence), reoccurence := 0]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
df1$visit_date <- as.Date(df1$visit_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
with(df1, ave(as.integer(visit_date), person_ID, FUN = 
        function(x) c(+(diff(x) < 90), 0)))
#[1] 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(person_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), visit_date = c("2/25/2001", 
"2/28/2001", "4/2/2001", "3/18/2004", "9/22/2004", "10/27/2004", 
"5/15/2008")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I could add another column with the first date of reoccurrence (if any), if it falls within the 90 days?

Comment: @alex can you update with the expected output.  Is it `2001-02-28` for the first one

Comment: Yes! And then row 6 would be NA because that observation isn't within 90 days.

Comment: @alex can you please post as a new question so that it becomes more clear. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Base R variant:

```r
reoccur <- function(x, lim=90) {
  m <- outer(x, x, `-`)
  m[upper.tri(m, diag=TRUE)] <- NA
  colSums(!is.na(m) & m >= 0 & m <= lim) > 0
}

### make your dates *dates*
dat$visit <- as.Date(dat$visit, format="%m/%d/%Y")

### calculate if you have reoccurrences
ave(as.numeric(dat$visit), dat$person_ID, FUN=reoccur)
# [1] 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

---

Data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(person_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), visit = c("2/25/2001", "2/27/2001", "4/2/2001", "3/18/2004", "9/22/2004", "10/27/2004", "5/15/2008")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

(I changed `"2/30/2001"` to `"2/27/2001"` to get a real `Date` out of it.)